# Identificadores em ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, ecmascript-6

Quais são os caracteres permitidos, ou o que é permitido, dentro de um nome (conhecido como "identificador") no [ECMAScript 6](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0)?

Tem regras entre identificadores e palavras-chave???

Comment: Curiosidade: por que você quer comparar com ES3 e não ES5.1? E, para constar, hoje a versão atual já é a ES7.

Comment: Olha tem um post muito completo falando sobre isso [aqui](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6)

Answer (score 12):

### Caracteres permitidos

> Quais são os caracteres permitidos dentro de um identificador no ES6?

Para começar, o nome de um identificador (**`IdentifierName`**, que dá origem à **`Identifier`**) é especificado nessa gramática:

```
IdentifierName ::
   * IdentifierStart
   * IdentifierName IdentifierPart
IdentifierStart ::
   * UnicodeIDStart
   * $
   * _
   * \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
IdentifierPart ::
   * UnicodeIDContinue
   * $
   * _
   * \ UnicodeEscapeSequence
   * <ZWNJ>
   * <ZWJ>
UnicodeIDStart ::
   * qualquer caractere na categoria “ID_Start”
UnicodeIDContinue ::
   * qualquer caractere na categoria “ID_Continue”
```

`IdentifierName` claramente significa *nome que começa com `IdentifierStart` e continua com 0 ou mais `IdentifierPart`<sub>s</sub>*. É recursivo, mas podemos pensar assim.

Os caracteres basicamente permitidos são `'$'` e `'_'`. Especialmente também o elemento lexical `UnicodeEscapeSequence`, aqueles `\uhhhh` e `\u{hex}`.

Os elementos `IdentifierStart` e `IdentifierPart` aceitam mais do que uma categoria do Unicode, pelo menos no ES**3**. No ES6 `IdentifierStart` aceita todos caracteres da categoria *ID_Start*, enquanto `IdentifierPart` aceita todos na *ID_Continue* e 2 caracteres inclusivos (*U+200C* e *U+200D*).

#### Dica

Veja, [Unicode Utilities: UnicodeSet](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp). Esse site avalia uma pattern e mostra uma lista de caracteres equivalentes (**set**).

Essa pattern...

```
[:age=5.1:]&[[:ID_Start:]]
```

resulta os caracteres da categoria *ID_Start* na versão 5.1 do Unicode. Para incluir uma categoria abreviada como *Pc*, use algo tipo `[:gc=Pc:]`

#### Avisos sobre o utilitário citado

- Alguns caracteres podem não aparecer no resultado do topo, talvez por conta do navegador. Para ter certeza de que todos os caracteres vão aparecer, ative a opção **Escape** para que caracteres não comuns no ASCII apareçam corretamente. Os caracteres fora do plano básico vão aparecer com `\UHHHHHHHH`, enquanto o resto vão aparecer normais ou na forma `\uHHHH`. Modifique o resultado como desejar.
- Até agora o utilitário organizou corretamente a ordem de decrescente à crescente nas sets resultadas para mim, no assunto de identificadores. Com categorias como `Zs` (certas quebras de linha) ele não organizou direito, então talvez você pode precisar organizar manualmente, ou utilizando uma ferramenta. Não é tão difícil fazer uma.

### Algumas regras

#### Regra do `UnicodeEscapeSequence`

- Um `UnicodeEscapeSequence` deve contribuir um caractere permitido no `IdentifierStart`, assim como no `IdentifierPart`. Isso é simplesmente porque esse escape pode resultar em qualquer caractere.

#### Identificadores reservados

Todos nós sabemos que palavras-chave (`ReservedWord`) devem aparecer no contexto certo. Algumas dessas palavras-chave são futuramente reservadas (`FutureReservedWord`).

Qualquer pedaço de código contido no modo estrito contém mais palavras-chave no elemento lexical `FutureReservedWord`. Consulte a seção [§ 11.6.2.2 Future Reserved Words](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-future-reserved-words).

E na pequena seção [§ 12.1.1 Static Semantics: Early Errors](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifiers-static-semantics-early-errors) estão alguns quebra-galhos de identificadores reservados.

Especialmente, algumas interpretadores restrigem a aparição de `UnicodeEscapeSequence`s dentro de palavras-chave (por exemplo, `instanceo\u{66}`) e excepcionam. Alguns interpretadores (como o de ActionScript 3 usado no mxmlc provavelmente) podem ignorar palavras-chave com `UnicodeEscape`s, mas isso significa que foi mal-implementado.