# Como validar um nome de identificador em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, identificador

Essa pergunta é possivelmente duplicada, mas eu procuro uma abordagem diferente. A situação é a seguinte: eu fiz um pequeno programa para criar um arquivo JSON, criando nomes e atribuindo valores. O destino do JSON quando lido será um objeto, então os nomes viram identificadores de propriedade. Seria interessante filtrar os nomes de campos de forma mais rigorosa, obedecendo os critérios da linguagem.

Editado: O Bruno Vianna alerta para o fato de que JSON é diferente de objeto literal, ainda que a estrutura seja a mesma. Fazer um JSON corretamente não resolve o problema já que tem regras diferentes (veja o exemplo).

O que eu consegui de informação são instruções sobre como criar um nome que não dê problemas na hora de desenvolver o código. Existe uma [página no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guia/Valores,_Vari%C3%A1veis_e_Literais) e também uma [questão similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177348/nomes-v%C3%A1lidos-em-javascript-ecmascript/203105) daqui com uma exaustiva resposta. Para o início do identificador é fácil: uma letra, _ ou $. O restante eu não achei um conjunto de caracteres ou expressão regular para buscar problemas, e há ainda os nomes reservados. Tudo isso tem que ser listado para um verificador. Minha alternativa até o momento é seguir o padrão de nomes de arquivo Unix, tirar os espaços, etc. o que é bastante conservador.

Alguém já fez um verificador? Conhece algum?

EDITADO:
Exemplo: esse JSON foi validado pelo JSONLint

```
var str = '{"prop+1": "valor1","%prop2": "valor2"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var res = '<h1>Teste</h1>';
res += '<li>' + obj["prop+1"] + '</li>';
res += '<li>' + obj["%prop2"] + '</li>';
res += '<li>' + obj.prop+1 + '</li>';
res += '<li>' + obj.%prop2 + '</li>';
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
```

O código não funcionou no jsfiddle - até achei que as propriedades seriam acessíveis entre aspas, mas não. De qualquer forma, são identificadores problemáticos que passam num primeiro momento (criação do JSON) mas podem dar problema mais adiante.

Comment: "Problema" é algo muito vago. Só se lembre, ao reformular sua pergunta, que um objeto literal não é o mesmo que o um objeto JSON, embora sua estrutura seja igual.

Comment: Eu realmente não entendi sua dúvida... Você pode colocar um exemplo?

Comment: Brunno: o problema é que o JSON não é objeto literal, senão seria fácil - só detectar o erro ao criar o JSON. Por isso preciso filtrar os identificadores pensando nas regras de um objeto literal - valeu a dica! @KhaosDoctor: realmente faltou um exemplo, coloquei lá.